# getUserMedia doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, getusermedia

I've got a problem with an application that uses the microphone. It seems to me, that the problem lies in getUserMedia(). The point is, that it works fine on Firefox, but Chrome doesn't prompt the user for the possibility of using the microphone. I think there's a bug in my code which makes getUserMedia() not work on Chrome as it should. Any ideas?

```
try {
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    audioContext = new AudioContext();
} catch (e) {
    updateStatus("Error");              }
    if (navigator.getUserMedia) navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true }, startUserMedia, function(e) {
        updateStatus("Error");
    });
    else updateStatus("Error");
```

---

```
function startUserMedia(stream) {
    var input = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    window.firefox_audio_hack = input; 
    var audioRecorderConfig = {errorCallback: function(x) {updateStatus("Error " + x);}};
    recorder = new AudioRecorder(input, audioRecorderConfig);
    // If a recognizer is ready, we pass it to the recorder
    if (recognizer) recorder.consumers = [recognizer];
    recorderReady = true;
    updateUI();
    updateStatus("Error");
};
```

Comment: If I go to a [demo site](http://demos.zingaya.com/webrtc/) in Chrome, everything works as expected, so it most likely is something with your code. However, I don't spot anything obvious. It would help if you could clean and format the code though.

Comment: Is there ANYTHING in the startUserMedia callback that chrome would not recognize? If there is, then that is your problem as the callback is not processed and not called.

Comment: gpgekko, done :) Could you help me now? :)

Comment: what does your console print out? can you post any errors in your console?